# pyWemo - NotifyManualToggle()

Tags: python

I have gotten pywemo to run.  It's finding my devices and I can change/get states.  I'm trying to enable callbacks when the light/device status changes.  I'm new to python, but not new to programming.  I found NotifyManualToggle() in the documentation, but I can't get the syntax correct on it.  Anyone have any code snippets that can show me how todo it?

I've tried creating a callback function and sending that to NotifyManualToggle().  Just not familiar with python enough to make this happen.